# Sitecore 9 how to establish Claims-based Active Directory Authorization

Tags: c#, active-directory, sitecore, adfs, sitecore9

in Sitecore 9 , i trying to Claims-based Active Directory Authorization(ADFS)

1. What is the difference between
   only Active Directory
   and  Active Directory use ADFS(Claims-based)
2. How to make
   Claims-based Active Directory Authorization
   (we have ADFS ADDS server and installed sitecore 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Active Directory module is meant for legacy systems upgrading to Sitecore 9 who have previously connected to an on-premise Active Directory authentication system. This does not use claims.

The new Federated Authentication options, which are disabled by default but can be enabled via configuration, will allow you to consume tokens using standard OWIN middleware.

Instructions for configuring Federated Authentication in Sitecore 9 can be found on the Sitecore documentation site:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/configure_federated_authentication

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I thought I was accessing AD using a token.
Can I ask you more question? why create AdfsLocalClaimsProviderTrust? for what

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer to that. Please post as a separate question and perhaps somebody will be able to answer that one here, on the Sitecore Forums, or on the Sitecore Stack Exchange.